# How do I print the values of hashsets that are saved in a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, hash

I have file (named `ter.txt`) that contains the hashsets content as below:

```
{"qty"=>"gfg", "unit"=>"gfg", "item"=>"xcv", "cost"=>"0.0", "salestax"=>"0.0"}
{"qty"=>"gdf", "unit"=>"g", "item"=>"gg", "cost"=>"0.0", "salestax"=>"0.0"}
```

I want to print the values of the hashsets. I've tried the following but I got an error of `undefined local variable or method 'item'`

```
file = File.open('ter.txt', 'r').map { |line| line.split("\n")[0] }
file.each do |hash|
    p hash
    p " #{hash[item]}"
end
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it demonstrates a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't save your data this way. This is a perfect case to use YAML. Write your file like:

```
---
- qty: gfg
  unit: gfg
  item: xcv
  cost: 0.0
  salestax: 0.0
- qty: gdf
  unit: g
  item: gg
  cost: 0.0
  salestax: 0.0
```

Then you can load it with:

```
require 'yaml'
data = YAML.load(File.read 'ter.txt')
```

Comment: I would add two points: to put your data into the file, use `File.open("ter.txt", "w") {|f| f << hsh.to_yaml }`, and to read it, you can use `YAML.load_file("ter.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

I saved your data in a file called *test.rb* file firstly. The I opened the file, and read each line and substitute all `=>` to `:`, to make this as a *json string*. Then used [`JSON::parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Parsing+JSON) method to transform each line of *json string* to `Hash` object. Here is the code I wrote to solve your problem :-

```
require 'json'

File.foreach("#{__dir__}/test.txt") do |line|
  p JSON.parse(line.strip.gsub("=>", ":")).values
end
```

Now I run the code from command prompt and got the output as you are looking for :-

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> ruby -vw test.rb
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [i686-linux]
["gfg", "gfg", "xcv", "0.0", "0.0"]
["gdf", "g", "gg", "0.0", "0.0"]
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby>
```